# Adding an image in Jade

Tags: html, pug

I have the following piece of Jade code :

```
a.brand(href="index.html") #{"Hello World"}
```

I am wondering how to replace the "Hello World" text with an image, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like

```
a.brand(href="index.html")
    img(src="image.png")
```